# Clojure: ^:dynamic in macros?

Tags: dynamic, macros, clojure

As some of you know I am implementing Shen in Clojure.
Since Shen has a dual namespace and all symbols evaluate to themselves I need a Clojure macro, which binds the symbol to itself and the value to a postfixed symbol.

Now also symbols like `*language*` have to be bound. But when I use the following macro with `*language*` as a parameter I get `Warning: *language* not declared dynamic and thus is not dynamically rebindable, but its name suggests otherwise. Please either indicate ^:dynamic *language* or change the name.`

```
(defmacro set [x y] 
  `(let [y# ~y]
    (def ^:dynamic ~x '~x)
    (intern *ns* (symbol (str (name ~x) "__varPoF__")))
    (def ^:dynamic ~(symbol (str (name x) "__varPoF__")) y#)
    y#))
```

Can someone tell me why this is not working?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The use of reader macros is wrong here. You have to use `with-meta`. I'm also not sure why you need the `intern` call.

```
(defmacro set
  [x y]
  (let [dynamic {:dynamic true}]
    `(let [y# ~y]
       (def ~(vary-meta x merge dynamic) '~x)
       (def ~(vary-meta (symbol (str (name x) "__varPoF__")) merge dynamic) y#)
       y#)))
```

Shameless self-promotion: [with-meta and the reader](http://kotka.de/blog/2009/12/with-meta_and_the_reader.html).

Answer (score 1):

What you receive is a `WARNING` due to the convention in Clojure < 1.3 for which vars named with "earmuffs", i.e. with leading and trailing starts, where dynamically rebindable.

Since [Clojure 1.3](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/1.3.x/changes.txt#L6) this is no longer the case, and the Reader throws that warning to, well, warn you that things might not be as you expect. It shouldn't break you code though, as `WARNING`s are not errors.

Comment: The problem here is, that I want to create a REPL for Shen, and the WARNINGS should not pop up there, since they don't have anything to do with Shen. Is there a possibility to suppress warnings, as there is e.g. in Java?

Comment: I guess rebinding `*err*` should fix it